# How to localize form builder - formio

Tags: angular, internationalization, i18next, formio

I am implementing a locale for our angular 10 application.
I am using ngx-translate to translate the application content.

We also have user creation forms, where application admins will create a custom form as per their requirements. For this, we are using [form.io](https://www.form.io/).
I am using a formio's form-builder which will give the drag and drop components to generate the form,
[image: form builder components]
[image]

Whatever components are available those all need to be translated based on application language selection. (Basic, Text Field, Text Area, Display, Data, Validation, etc.)
I have gone through the [formiojs](https://github.com/formio/formio.js/tree/76ef892261c7c6ca12fc450a34cb94f7ce464029/src/components/_classes/component/editForm) code and the [document](https://github.com/formio/formio.js/wiki)
Also, I am looking for something exactly like the [git issue](https://github.com/formio/formio.js/issues/1639) which already exists, but it does not have enough information which I can start through.

Looking for a guideline that helps me to translate the form-builder components and their properties.

Thank you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been through this. Use i18n with formio like this:

```
var trad_form = JSON.parse(your_json_translation);
Formio.createForm(document.getElementById(id_element),
            your_json_form_structure,
            {
                readOnly: is_read_only,
                language: selected_language,
                i18n: your_json_trad_form
            }).then(function (form) { ... });
```

And a small part of the json file for the german translation for example would look like this:

```
var your_json_translation = { "de": { "Number": "Nummer", "Right (Right-aligned)": "Rechts (rechtsbündig)", "Bottom": "Unten", "Placeholder": "Platzhalter", "The placeholder text that will appear when this field is empty.": "Der Platzhaltertext, der angezeigt wird, wenn dieses Feld leer ist.", "Description": "Beschreibung"}};
```

You have to create that file with all the labels existing in formio.

Comment: Aren't there any ready-made translations yet?